# Laravel Error - MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

Tags: ajax, laravel

when i try to submit a form with Ajax,i get this Error,**MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message**.
i guess problem is in routing, but when i tested without Ajax it works fine
here is my Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "{{ route('submitProfile') }}",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, firstName:firstName, lastName:lastName, email:email, mobile:mobile},
            success: function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

my route is:

```
Route::get('/edit/profile',[
    'uses' => 'UserController@getEditProfile',
    'as' => 'editProfile'
]);

Route::post('/ajax/edit/profile',[
    'uses' => 'UserController@postEditProfile',
    'as' => 'submitProfile'
]);
```

and in my controller i have this functions:

```
public function postEditProfile(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'firstName' => 'required',
        'lastName' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'mobile' => 'required',
    ]);

    $user = \Auth::user();
    $user->firstName = $request['firstName'];
    $user->lastName = $request['lastName'];
    $user->email = $request['email'];
    $user->mobile = $request['mobile'];
    $user->save();

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'its done!'
    ]);
}
```

thank you.

Comment: Don't you have a redirect from url without slash to url with slash? It may be the reason of such kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this for your route

```
Route::post('/ajax/edit/profile',[
    'uses' => 'UserController@postEditProfile'
])->name('submitProfile');
```

Comment: thank you, ajax call now works but after that the same error accrued